# Crashlytics Won't Pass "Add a Run Script Build Phase"

Tags: xcode, crashlytics

After installing Crashlytics and checking out the source code for the project I am helping out with, I add a build phase script and add the following code:

`./Crashlytics.framework/run <api_key>`

This initially worked until I blew away my changes. I then tried to build and was missing my `Crashlytics.h` file. I then tried to reconnect the app but I get stuck at the "Add a Run Script Build Phase".

I have tried removing Crashlytics and reinstalling it without success. Does anyone have insight into how I can get things running again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652476/crashlytics-app-add-new-app-stuck-on-add-run-script-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by manually grabbing the Crashlytics files that are generated and import them into the project. They are generated in the Crashlytics folder when you add the run script build phase, but not imported.

Answer (score 2):

Check `Debug Information Format` for `Debug`, and `Release`. They should be `DWARF with dSYM File`.

`dSYM` file is in order to show debug symbols. The `Run Script` will upload `dSYM` file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have pasted Run command bellow the Shell `/bin/sh` field:

[image]

Comment: unchecking Run script only when installing worked for me