# Crashlytics.app add new app stuck on "Add Run Script" step

Tags: java, ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

Found Crashlytics.app issue. App not handling Xcode Build Success notification.
To resolve this issue set "Build Settings -> Debug information format -> DWARF with dSYM File" for Debug mode.

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: Been debugging this for hours, and boom! This solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks and i think this information we need from fabric !!